# How to change title tag at page after loaded post?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I have sequence stack of filters\actions in custom plugin WP:

```
    add_action('the_post', 'post_callback');

   add_filter('the_content', 'modify_content');

    add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_filter_post_titles' );
```

Inside callback `post_callback` I modify `$post` object on custom values:

```
$post->post_title = "my";
$post->post_content = "my content";
```

Then, after all actions and filters I try to change HTML tag `title` on the page. To replace it on value from `$post->post_title`.

But, it brings some issues:

First is, that `HEAD` part of page had built before modification `$post` content.

I can assume that there is any function, that pushed all HTML page(view) to client, think it is the right way to replace title tag on custom value.

What do you think?